# Display Images in GridView from ExternalMediaDirs

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter

This app capture images and stores them in /storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.camerapp/ and I want to display them in GridView.

Firstly, I made gridview in activity_display.xml, set adapter in DisplayActivity and implemented the ImageAdapter.java, to begin with I used icon form drawable to display in the girdview, but I'm not sure how to pass images from where they are stored.

How do I replace images from Drawable to images form externalMeidaDires

activty_display.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DisplayActivity">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="1dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="1dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

DisplayActivity.java

```
package com.example.cameraapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }
}
```

ImageAdapter.java

```
package com.example.cameraapp;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context mContext;

    File mFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.cameraapp/one.jpg");
    Uri mUri = Uri.fromFile(mFile);

    public Uri[] uriArray = {
        mUri, mUri, mUri
    };

    public int[] imageArray = {
            R.drawable.and_icon,
            R.drawable.and_icon, R.drawable.and_icon,
            R.drawable.and_icon, R.drawable.and_icon,
            R.drawable.and_icon, R.drawable.and_icon,
            R.drawable.and_icon, R.drawable.and_icon,
    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return imageArray[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        // imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);

        Bitmap mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath());

        //imageView.setImageURI(uriArray[position]);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(600, 350));

        return imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);` You will not load from resource so remove that line. Replace by something like `imageView.setImageUri(uriArray[position]);`. The uri's come from a File.list() of your directory and they look for instance like `file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.camerapp/mypicture.jpg`.

Comment: But putting the original images (with a big resolution) in a gridview is no good idea. After you got this working your second task is to resize them to smaller resolution.

Comment: I tried doing what you said as below,  I'm displaying an just this one image to test things out, but I'm getting a arrayoutofbound Error.
After this I will use thumbnails instead of full images.
```

File mFile = new File("/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/com.example.camerapp/one.jpg");
    Uri mUri = Uri.fromFile(mFile);

    public Uri[] uriArray = {
        mUri, mUri, mUri
    };

```

Comment: Put all code in your post. Not in a comment. And post complete code and complete logcat. Adaot your old code here to show what you have now..

Comment: I've updated the post, the activity opens up but when I try to scroll it crashes.

Comment: Used bitmap instead of URI and it stopped crashing, now I have to figure out how read all the file in a directory, and pass that list of images to gridview